# Could InAppSettingsKit do this, or is there another library?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, settings, inappsettingskit

I'm trying to implement a system whereby the user is initially presented with a single tablecell, in a uitableview (grouped style), within a uinavigationview.

```
  ---------------
+ | add record  |
  ---------------
```

When they click on the cell, they are pushed onto a new screen where they fill in a few textviews (perhaps imbedded in a tableview's cells)

```
  ---------------
  | (name)      |
  ---------------
  | (phone num) |
  ---------------
```

Then when they go back, they can see the new record as well as the 'add record' cell.

```
  ---------------
  | record  1   |
  ---------------
+ | add record  |
  ---------------
```

(When they go into record 1 again there would be a delete button)

Is there any sample code or libraries which would achieve this? What about InAppSettingsKit? It's more the presentation I'm concerned with. I can handle the saving of data myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of InAppSettingsKit includes `IASKSettingsStore` which allows you to use a different store instead of `NSUserDefaults`. For instance, you can store the settings in a plist. Combined with custom cells (`IASKCustomViewSpecifier`), you should be able to accomplish your task. Unfortunately, there's no complete sample code for this scenario yet. You're welcome to contribute, though ;)